# Python mmap replace (substitute) using regex

Tags: python, regex, replace, mmap

All you Python wizards,

I am reading a huge file (up to 8GB) into memory using mmap, and I want to replace some strings using regular expressions, then saving it. How to achieve that?

```
    >>> import mmap
    >>> import re
    >>> f = open('lorem.txt', 'r+')
    >>> m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    >>> m.size()
    737
```

The issue I am having is that the replacement string is shorter than the replaced one, so when I try to run the substitution, I get an error message `IndexError: mmap slice assignment is wrong size`.

```
    >>> m[:] = re.sub('[Ll]orem', 'a', m[:])
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    IndexError: mmap slice assignment is wrong size
```

If I try;

```
    >>> a = re.sub('[Ll]orem','a', m[:])
    >>> len(a)
    733
    >>> m.write(a)
    >>> m.flush(0,len(a))
    >>> m.size()
    737
```

As you can see, the mapped file m still has the same size. Which means it's not the same as the substituted text!

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the file so gigantic that `re.sub(regex, replacement, yourfile.read())` is out of the question?

Comment: Check the note on [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html): `flush([offset, size])¶
Flushes changes made to the in-memory copy of a file back to disk. Without use of this call there is no guarantee that changes are written back before the object is destroyed. If offset and size are specified, only changes to the given range of bytes will be flushed to disk; otherwise, the whole extent of the mapping is flushed.`

Comment: @timgeb, yes the files are huge (up to 8GB each)

Comment: and.... if You're writing to file before mmap'ing it: `Note If you want to create a memory-mapping for a writable, buffered file, you should flush() the file first. This is necessary to ensure that local modifications to the buffers are actually available to the mapping.` From the same documentation page.

Comment: @RikiLyng okay, thanks for clarifying. You should probably put that information in your question because this is pretty relevant.

Comment: Linux `mmap` does not provide any functionality for resizing. You'll need to truncate the file manually.

Comment: @Kamiccolo, Yes I tried that, and I went through the doc, but the file size is still the same, after `m.flush(0, len(a))`

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, any ideas on how to truncate the file using python? and what if the changes make the file larger? is there a way to increase its size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out that mmap() cannot be used to increase (or decrease) the size of a file. mmap()'s function is to memory map a portion of a file.
the easiest way is to truncate the file size to the new size before closing it:

```
>>> f.truncate(len(a))
>>> f.close()
```

and if you think that the file size would increase after the replacing, then just increase its size (for example double it) after opening it:

```
>>> f = open('lorem.txt', 'r+')
>>> f.truncate(os.path.getsize('lorem.txt') * 2)
>>> m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
>>> m.size()
1474
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-write the file if you intend to replace a section with a length different than the beginning length. At least from the beginning of the string to the end of the file.

Consider using collections of smaller files or another format that allows for variable lengths that can be interpreted by whatever process eventually reads that file.